# Como instalar PIP em arquivo requirements.txt do Odoo

Tags: python, pip

Eu quero instalar o *Odoo* em um servidor *ubuntu 14.04*. Porém, para funcionar com a legislação brasileira, é preciso instalar algumas dependências *pip* para os modulos:

dependências pip para os módulos:

```
Babel==1.3
Jinja2==2.7.3
Mako==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow==2.7.0
Python-Chart==1.39
PyYAML==3.11
Werkzeug==0.9.6
argparse==1.2.1
decorator==3.4.0
docutils==0.12
feedparser==5.1.3
gdata==2.0.18
gevent==1.0.2
greenlet==0.4.7
jcconv==0.2.3
lxml==3.4.1
mock==1.0.1
ofxparse==0.16
passlib==1.6.2
psutil==2.2.0
psycogreen==1.0
psycopg2==2.5.4
pyPdf==1.13
pydot==1.0.2
pyparsing==2.0.3
pyserial==2.7
python-dateutil==2.4.0
python-ldap==2.4.19
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2014.10
pyusb==1.0.0b2
qrcode==5.1
reportlab==3.1.44
requests==2.6.0
six==1.9.0
suds-jurko==0.6
vobject==0.6.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
XlsxWriter==0.7.7
xlwt==0.7.5
openpyxl==2.4.0-b1
boto==2.38.0
odoorpc
suds_requests
http://labs.libre-entreprise.org/frs/download.php/897/pyxmlsec-0.3.1.tar.gz
plotly==1.13.0
pandas==0.19.2
relatorio==0.6.4
xlrd==1.0.0
urllib3==1.22
pyopenssl==17.2.0
```

O *Odoo* possui em sua pasta o `requirements.txt, o correto é inserir todos esses requerimentos acima e depois informar os comandos:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $(grep -v '^#' apt-requirements)

sudo pip install --upgrade pip

sudo pip install -r pip-requirements
```

- **Seria exatamente isso?**

Eu não tenho nenhum conhecimento com *phyton*.

Comment: existe esse arquivo : pip-requirements.txt ?

Comment: Exatamente amigo, o Odoo tem o requirements.txt onde fica todas as dependências acima, porem eu preciso instalar outras dependencias brasileira para funcionar com a legislação daqui. Então eu preciso instalar as seguintes dependencias:

python-cnab
python-boleto
pytrustnfe

Então, no caso basta acrescentar o que está acima no requirements.txt e da os comandos que você falou?

Comment: Sim..basta adicionar suas novas libs ao arquivo e executá-lo normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Na página da Trustcode no Github tem um [repositório com um tutorial de instalação](https://github.com/Trust-Code/Tutorial-Instalacao) do Odoo com os aplicativos da Trustcode para implementação das regras contábeis e fiscais brasileira. No mesmo diretório também tem um [script para instalação automática](https://github.com/Trust-Code/Tutorial-Instalacao/blob/master/install_odoo_trustcodebr.sh).

De toda forma se não for utilizar o script da Trustcode é só pegar o arquivo requirements.txt que você mencionou e acrescentar as dependências para a localização brasileira mantida pela trustcode.

```
pytrustnfe
python-boleto
python-cnab
```

Salvar o arquivo e rodar o comando que você mencionou:

```
pip install -r pip-requirements
```